# Cheapest speedlight for Nikon with autofocus assist beam?

Tags: nikon, low-light, hotshoe-flash

I shoot low light with Nikon D3300 and Yongnuo YN-460 speed light. Most of my pictures are out of focus.

I'm on a budget. What is the lowest-priced speed light for Nikon that has an AF assist beam?

Comment: Different flashes tend to be priced differently in different countries. If one compares the price of three different flash models, their prices very well could fall in a different order in various countries or regions.

Comment: Does the AF assist light built into the camera not help?

Comment: @Blrfl The camera's AF assist light only lights up in very limited scenarios, i.e. central AF point selected or when using Auto Area AF. Using the assist light of a flash allows it to light up when using more AF points.

Comment: @KamenMinkov That makes sense.  The assist light is one of the first things I shut off when I get a new body, so I hadn't really had much chance to learn its limitations.

Comment: @Blrfl Moreover PDAF gets so much better that many of the high end bodies now omit the assist light.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the Neewer VK-750II for Nikon, $50 at Amazon.  It does TTL and manual flash, and slave flash remotely.

A review including focus assist at http://www.scantips.com/lights/vk750.html

Comment: does it have af assist beam

Comment: Yes, see the review mentioned.